# Jasmine jQuery elements differ than browser

Tags: javascript, jquery, typescript, jasmine, karma-jasmine

I'm working on component with simple notifications, using TypeScript, jQuery and Karma/Jasmine for testing.

This is my method to get compiled template as jQuery element.

```
    public getTemplate(): JQuery {
    if (!this._$template) {
        this._$template = this._compileTemplate();
    }

    console.log(this._$template);

    return this._$template;
}
```

I created instance `n` of the class and try it in Chrome

[Different results image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pXYoU.png)

As I can see the first result is proper, console-logged result from the method's body. Second is returned value, which looks like HTMLElement (which is not, instanceof return false). And then `instanceof` this value is jQuery.

Also trying to call method on this strange-jquery element is successful, both jQuery and mine methods.

**So the first question is how and why there is such behaviour?**

Secondly I have simple test in Jasmine

```
    it('has getTemplate() method returns JQuery', () => {

    // expect(singleNotification.getTemplate().jquery).not.toBeUndefined();

    expect(singleNotification.getTemplate() instanceof jQuery).toBeTruthy();
});
```

The commented test is working, but this is hack. Uncommented, proper `insanceof` test fails on Karma, while succeeds on Chrome! **Why?**

PS. Im running Karma via Firefox and also my browser test return proper jQuery object in Firefox both times. I would have considered it as a Chrome bug, but this behaviour doesn't look proper considering tests.